# ProgressBar (Spinner) is filling the whole screen

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-progressbar

As the title says, I can't get the progress bar to shrink at all. Currently it continues to fill the whole screen. I assume it has something to do with me using it in a viewstub? Anyway, here is my code.

- This is my main layout. I'm using viewstub and will only inflate it when the framelayout is changing fragments

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  ....
       <FrameLayout
  ....
       />

       <ViewStub android:id="@+id/loadSpinner"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/subView"
        android:layout="@layout/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ....

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  ```
- Here is the ProgressBar (progress_spinner.xml) which will be loaded into the viewstub

  ```
  <ProgressBar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/progressSpinner"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_spinner">
  </ProgressBar>
  ```
- This is my custom_spinner.xml, which I was hoping would set the size of the spinner

  ```
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:duration="1"
      android:toDegrees="360" >

      <shape
          android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
          android:shape="ring"
          android:thicknessRatio="8"
          android:useLevel="false" >
      <size
          android:height="48dp"
          android:width="48dp" />

      <gradient
          android:centerColor="@color/color_preloader_center"
          android:centerY="0.50"
          android:endColor="@color/color_preloader_end"
          android:startColor="@color/color_preloader_start"
          android:type="sweep"
          android:useLevel="false" />
  </shape>
  ```
- This is what I get, it always fills the whole screen
  [image]

Comment: I can't be certain from your pared-down layout, but it's likely due to it being a direct child of `DrawerLayout`. Any direct child of `DrawerLayout` that's not a drawer is laid out to fill it. Move it into the content `ViewGroup`, if you want it to keep its size as you've set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mike suggeste do it like

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ....
         <FrameLayout
    ....
         />
    <FrameLayout>
     <ViewStub android:id="@+id/loadSpinner"
          android:inflatedId="@+id/subView"
          android:layout="@layout/progress_spinner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
         </FrameLayout>

     ....

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```